# openvpn client setup in terminal

Tags: 14.04, networking, vpn, openvpn, client

The task that i'm trying to accomplish is simple: configure my ubuntu client  so that i can connect to internet via openvpn file by wifi.

The connection with openvpn server is established, after `sudo openvpn file.ovpn`, i get in output `Initialization Sequence Completed`

I can't ping google but i can ping the openvpn server.

```
    user@computer:~$ ifconfig     
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1b:b9:b2:bb:a9  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:220 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:220 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:16057 (16.0 KB)  TX bytes:16057 (16.0 KB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.8.0.34  P-t-P:10.8.0.33  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:15 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:75 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:1191 (1.1 KB)  TX bytes:4540 (4.5 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:18:4d:70:68:26  
          inet addr:192.168.0.12  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::218:4dff:fe70:6826/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:148 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:304 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:30520 (30.5 KB)  TX bytes:47304 (47.3 KB)
          Interrupt:21 Memory:ff5e0000-ff5f0000 

user@computer:~$
```